# Lattice Diamond/Reveal throws error with Bitstream File programming

Tags: fpga, lattice

I recently started using Lattice MachX03L device for a project. I have a design and with Reveal I wanted to look at the signals. When I program a JEDEC file into the FPGA I can observe the signals in Reveal and observe how the design works in the Hardware but with Bitstream file I get the following error :

> ERROR - ERROR: core1 incorrect pattern readout. <a
> href='file:///C:/lscc/diamond/3.11_x64/docs/manuals/troubleshoot.pdf#FailurePoints'>See
> Reveal Troubleshooting Guide for more details on Failure Points (1) to
> (6)</a>.

A closer look in the *reveal_debug.log* shows me the following information

> [10:34:05] Connecting cableserver to run Reveal debugger....                                                                                                                                                                  
> [10:34:05] @Connect                                                                                                                                                                                                           
> [10:34:05] @SetSharableApplications,2,Reveal,Mico                                                                                                                                                                             \
> [10:34:08] @SetCablePort,USB2,FTUSB-0,8,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
> . 
> . 
> . 
> [10:34:08] @Set LA Start/Stop readback                                                                                                                                                                                        
> [10:34:08] @Set LA Start/Stop                                                                                                                                                                                                 
> [10:34:08] #Reveal IP Version = 1_6_042617                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [10:34:08] @Get Pattern                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> **[10:34:08] #pattern readout = 0                                                                                                                                                                                               
>
> [10:34:08] #pattern expected = A5A5**                                                                                                                                                                                           
> [10:34:08] ERROR: core1 incorrect pattern readout. <a href='file:///C:/lscc/diamond/3.11_x64/docs/manuals/troubleshoot.pdf#FailurePoints'>See Reveal Troubleshooting Guide for more details on Failure Points (1) to (6)</a>. 
> [10:34:09] @UnlockCable                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> [10:34:09] @ReleaseCablePort                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> [10:34:09] @Disconnect                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
> [10:34:14] #Reveal IP Version = 1_6_042617                                                                                                                                                                                    
> [10:34:14] @Get Pattern                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> **[10:34:14] #pattern readout = 0                                                                                                                                                                                               
>
> [10:34:14] #pattern expected = A5A5**                                                                                                                                                                                           
> [10:34:14] ERROR: core1 incorrect pattern readout. <a href='file:///C:/lscc/diamond/3.11_x64/docs/manuals/troubleshoot.pdf#FailurePoints'>See Reveal Troubleshooting Guide for more details on Failure Points (1) to (6)</a>. 
> [10:34:14] @UnlockCable                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> [10:34:14] @ReleaseCablePort                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> [10:34:14] @Disconnect                                                                                                                                                                                                        
> [10:34:16] @ReleaseCablePort                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> [10:34:16] @Disconnect                                                                                                                                                                                                \

As it can be seen, the Diamond and Reveal Analyzer tries a couple of times to find the reveal file but the pattern expected and the pattern read are different leading to the error.

Does the Bitstream file not support Reveal? Unfortunately, I found no Documentation on this issue.

The Bitstream file is needed by the software developers to integrate it into their design. Therefore, I want to observe the signals in Reveal using the Bitstream file to be sure that it works as intended.

Should I opt any option so that the BIT file does not throw an error regarding pattern readout?

With best regards,

Hemanth.

Comment: what does the "troubleshooting guide" say that is referred to there? This just sounds like a communication problem, or a damaged FPGA.

Comment: Unfortunately, Troubleshooting guide has no reference whatsoever that points to the error "core1 incorrect pattern readout". I would rule out damaged FPGA as the debugging using .jed file is possible. Regarding communication problem : My wild guess is that the access to the Bitstream file is restricted and hence the pattern read is not possible. But I am just hoping that is not the issue.